# Send model value to observer.next();

Tags: angular

I have a function like below. I am trying to figure out how to send userDetails to the observer.next()

```
  getUserDetails(userId: string): Observable<GetUserByIdModel> {
    const url = `${this.candidateUrl}/Get`;
    this._http.get<any>(url + '/' + userId).subscribe((resp) => {
      const userDetails: GetUserByIdModel = {
        firstname: 'Joyce',
        contactChannels: [
          { type: 1, value: 'test@gmail.com' },
          { type: 2, value: '0111111111' }
        ],
      };
    })

    return new Observable((observer) => {
      observer.next(userDetails);
      observer.complete();
    });

  }
```

Currently I get "Cannot find name 'userDetails'" even if I change  const userDetails: GetUserByIdModel to a let/var userDetails: GetUserByIdModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is transform the response that you're getting from the API call. Which is a perfect situation to use the Rxjs `map` operator. Here's how:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

getUserDetails(userId: string): Observable < GetUserByIdModel > {
  const url = `${this.candidateUrl}/Get`;
  return this._http.get < any > (url + '/' + userId).pipe(
    map(resp => {
      const userDetails: GetUserByIdModel = {
        firstname: 'Joyce',
        contactChannels: [{
            type: 1,
            value: 'test@gmail.com'
          },
          {
            type: 2,
            value: '0111111111'
          }
        ],
      };
      return userDetails;
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to return user when you get response from subscriber ? If answer is yes you can add returning inside `subscribe` or you want to return a new Observable because you have someone subscribed to this Observable you should do something like this:

1. First of all declare a variable

```
userDetails: GetUserByIdModel = {};
```

2. Inside your subscriber use this variable

```
getUserDetails(userId: string): Observable<GetUserByIdModel> {
    const url = `${this.candidateUrl}/Get`;
    this._http.get<any>(url + '/' + userId).subscribe((resp) => {
      this.userDetails = {
        firstname: 'Joyce',
        contactChannels: [
          { type: 1, value: 'test@gmail.com' },
          { type: 2, value: '0111111111' }
        ],
      };
    })

    return new Observable((observer) => {
      observer.next(this.userDetails);
      observer.complete();
    });

  }
```

But it doesn't make sense to return a new variable inside subscriber, it make sense to return the response what you get from subscriber, something like this:

```
observer: Subject<any>  = new BehaviorSubject<any>;

getUserDetails(userId: string): Observable<GetUserByIdModel> {
    const url = `${this.candidateUrl}/Get`;
    this._http.get<any>(url + '/' + userId).subscribe((resp) => {

    // Now you emitting new data as soon as possible you get data 
    this.observer.next(resp);
    })

  }
```

and in other place you'll have something like this

```
observer.subscriber(data => {
  // and here you'll have data from that observer
  console.log(data)
})
```

Please be more clear next time, and if you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: If you find useful what i wrote above you can up vote my answer.
Usually you use Subjects for sharing data in multiple components and you should put this logic in a service